# Pandas: Capturing the warning messages while reading the pipe delimited file

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading  pipe delimited data from a text file. There are some parsing issues and I am handing the same while `pd.read_csv(error_bad_lines=False)`

```
files = [f for f in filepath for f in os.listdir(filepath)]
df_f=[]
for i in files:
  df = df = pd.read_csv(i,usecols=col_lst,sep='|',engine='python',encoding='iso-8859-1',error_bad_lines=False)
  df_f.append(df)
```

The above method is removing the bad lines due to `|` parsing issues and going ahead.

**Objective:**
Can I get a list of warning messages for the bad lines in the above example and create list of the same.

Eg.

```
df_f =[]
bad_line =[]
for i in files:
  df = df = pd.read_csv(i,usecols=col_lst,sep='|',engine='python',encoding='iso-8859-1',error_bad_lines=False)
  #Pseudo Code Below. Need assistance in building it correctly
  if bad_lines:
    bad_line.append(bad_lines)
  df_f.append(df)
```

So in other words how can I append the warning messages into `bad_line` list.

Any thought on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do the same while redirecting errors to a log file. Basically I replaced `os` with `pathlib` as it is more readable. I turned `warning_bad_lines` to true and that was it.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import contextlib

import pandas as pd

# variables replace with real ones
CSVS_DIR = './data'
LOG_DIR = './logs'
COL_LIST = ['your_list', '...'] 

# create log dir if not exist
Path(LOG_DIR).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

# direct warning to log.txt
with open(f'{LOG_DIR}\log.txt', 'w') as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stderr(f):

        dfs_list = [pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=COL_LIST,sep='|',engine='python',encoding='iso-8859-1',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True, ) for csv_file in Path(CSVS_DIR).glob('*.csv')]

        df_master = pd.concat(dfs_list)
```

If we don’t want log files, we can use `warning` library

```py
import warnings
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

# variables replace with real ones
CSVS_DIR = './data'
COL_LIST = ['your_list', '...'] 

# direct warning to variable:

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:

    dfs_list = [pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=COL_LIST,sep='|',engine='python',encoding='iso-8859-1',error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True, ) for csv_file in Path(CSVS_DIR).glob('*.csv')]

    df_master = pd.concat(dfs_list)
    df_bad_lines_list = [str(bad.message) for bad in w]
```

Comment: I do not want to create any log directory. Instead I want to capture the warning message in a list. So in your code, if I do the some modification (as commented lines), hope the should work.

Comment: Ah okay. I usually read the log file, afterwards. Let me edit a way to add it as list without log file

Comment: Actually, I shall INSERT the bad_line string to postgresql as an Entry. However, I need to figure out for a single `.csv` file there could be multiple bad_lines. Hence, to ask you, `df_bad_lines_list` is it a dataframe? And `bad.message` comes from `warning.catch_warning() `?

Comment: Ah! Now we will have to write our flow a bit different to include details. This is why I usually opt for log files, and create a separate task to update my database on progress, failures, etc from logs. The log file or the message includes the file name and lines causing issues, no?

Comment: Yes. besides, `df_bad_lines_list` is creating a blank list despite bad lines.

Comment: I will try recreate your issue and try on my side

Comment: I have use `f_in_m = io.StringIO()
                  bad_lines = []
                  with redirect_stderr(f_in_m):` method and it is working as expected.